# Change position of facets in facet wrap sorted by years

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, facet, facet-wrap

I want to change the order and labs of my `ggplot` boxplot.
This is what I have so far:

```
ggplot(total_nr_obj_week_corr.3, aes(x=distance, y=n)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar")+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(~year_month, strip.position = "bottom",scales = "free", nrow=2)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits = c(0, 70), breaks = seq(0, 80, by = 10)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("0", "5","10", "15","20"), breaks = c("0", "5","10", "15","20"))+
  theme(strip.placement="outside", 
        strip.background = element_rect(color="black",
fill="white",size = rel(1)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, r = 0 , b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10 , b = 0, l = 0)))
```

**This is my plot**

[image]

I want to change the position of the different facets to the following:

- First row 2017 05-08
- Second row 2018 05-09

I tried `as.table = F` in `facet_wrap()`, but still do not get the correct order. Secondly I want to change the labels. Below the x-axis, I want the month(05-08/09), and above each row on big label per row with the year (2017/2018).

I googled everything for hours now but could not find a solution. I also tried `facet_grid`, but this did not give me the result I want.

Thank you!!

Comment: Since it's [not a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I can't add specific code to help, but to change the `facet_wrap`, you can cast `year_month` to a factor with levels corresponding to your preferred ordering. When you create the `factor`, you can also add a `labels` argument that would help provide a year label above each facet, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352923/how-to-create-a-facetted-plot-with-title-and-subtitle-specific-to-each-facet).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the levels of year_month, ok first we make a function to produce your plot, note that I included a facet_order, with which I relevel your year_month with:

```
func=function(DA,facet_order){

ggplot(data=DA, aes(x=distance, y=n)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar")+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(~factor(year_month,levels=facet_order), strip.position = "bottom",scales = "free", nrow=2)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),limits = c(0, 70), breaks = seq(0, 80, by = 10)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("0", "5","10", "15","20"), breaks = c("0", "5","10", "15","20"))+
  theme(strip.placement="outside", 
        strip.background = element_rect(color="black",
fill="white",size = rel(1)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, r = 0 , b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10 , b = 0, l = 0))) 
}
```

And I simulate something that looks like your data:

```
library(ggplot2)

DATES = c("2017 05","2017 06","2017 07","2017 08",
 "2018 05","2018 06","2018 07","2018 08","2018 09")

total_nr_obj_week_corr.3 = lapply(DATES,function(i){
  data.frame(
  distance=factor(rep(seq(0,20,by=5),each=10)),
  n = rnbinom(50,mu=20,siz=1),
  year_month = i
)
})

total_nr_obj_week_corr.3 = do.call(rbind,total_nr_obj_week_corr.3)
```

Now if we use the original levels, we get back something similar to your plot:

```
lvl=levels(total_nr_obj_week_corr.3$year_month)
func(total_nr_obj_week_corr.3,lvl)+ggtitle("original levels")
```

[image]

One quick way to "transpose" your levels:

```
NCOL=5
NROW=2
LAY_FACET = matrix(NA,ncol=NCOL,nrow=NROW)
LAY_FACET[1:length(lvl)]=lvl
new_lvl = na.omit(c(t(LAY_FACET)))

func(total_nr_obj_week_corr.3,new_lvl)+ggtitle("new levels")
```

[image]